# SparkJarProcessor heap memory issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-sagemaker

i am using SparkJarProcessor in AWS to run Sagemaker pipeline. basically jar file create a graph with millions of nodes and do some calculations. After a while it crashes giving following error.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 761"...
```

i was using ml.r5.12xlarge instance (has 48 VCPU & 386gb ram).when i checked the memory utilization in the CloudWatch it was around 2.5% only. I have tried passing job_arguments,

'--driver-memory' , '15g'
'--executor-memory' , '15g'
'--deploy-mode' , 'cluster'

but seems no effect on this. Some suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Recommend cutting a ticket to AWS support with all the code needed to reproduce the issue.